# How to eliminate a duplicate record which all the columns are null

Tags: sql

I have a table and I am getting duplicate records for some ids. I need to delete duplicate records based on the ID and having condition like all the columns are null for that ID. If the columns have some value, I need to keep that record. But some IDs have all the columns are null but that are not duplicated. I need to keep that records.

My input table is like this:

[image]

And the output result should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Please read this before asking: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/1987020

You'll get more response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create a table with the test data you supplied:

```
CREATE TABLE SGR (ID INT, item_no INT, fee NUMERIC(10,2))
INSERT INTO SGR VALUES
(895, 110, 179.5), 
(895, NULL, NULL), 
(741, NULL, NULL), 
(2021, NULL, NULL), 
(2021, 116, 89.6), 
(768, NULL, NULL)
```

Delete any records from the table where both item_no and fee are null, and there's another row in the table with the same ID where either field is not null:

```
DELETE FROM SGR
WHERE item_no IS NULL AND fee IS NULL
AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SGR s WHERE id = sgr.ID AND (item_no IS NOT NULL OR fee IS NOT NULL))
```

Then when you query the table:

```
SELECT * FROM SGR
```

You get this:

```
ID      item_no fee
895     110     179.50
741     NULL    NULL
2021    116     89.60
768     NULL    NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Make recursive CTE with order by and number reference value. then delete records from CTE. Duplicate Rows will be delete from physical table.